# how to pass 2D array by using OS mailbox?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, nios

I am asked to pass a 2D array through the OS mailbox in NiosII, for example:

```
mailbox=OSMboxCreate((void *)0);
INT8U return_code = OS_NO_ERR;
MemoryPartition = OSMemCreate(&array_a[0][0], 3, 4*ARRAY_SIZE*ARRAY_SIZE, &return_code);
void function1()

    INT32S (*array_a)[32];
    array_a = OSMemGet(MemoryPartition, &return_code);
    alt_ucosii_check_return_code(return_code);
    return_code = OSMboxPost(mailbox, (void *)(array_a));
    alt_ucosii_check_return_code(return_code);
void function2()

    INT32S (*data_array)[32];
    data_array = (INT32S *)OSMboxPend(mailbox, 0, &return_code);
    alt_ucosii_check_return_code(return_code);
    for(i=0;i<32;i++){
        for(j=0;j<32;j++){
            data_array[i][j]= 1;
        }
    }
    printf("done");
```

since I need to allocate the memory for array_a, so I use array of pointers while each pointer can point to a 1D array. However the program is not working properly since the array is not passed. No error message is shown and "done" is not printing on the console. The code is working on passing 1D array (*array_a and *data_array in instead of array of pointers),but I cannot find where I made the mistake.